# Derivation of Hofman-Maldacena Bounds

Tags: field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

I am trying to study the section where the author of the article - https://gitlab.com/davidsd/lorentzian-cft-notes tries to outline the derivation of the Hofman-Maldacena bounds in Section 6.2. I have attached the image of the part I am confused by.

[image]

The equation given for the bilinear form (112) is in squares and quadratics of delta functions and $n_i$, where $\vec{z} = (1, -\vec{n})$ and $z^2=0$. However, the article says that by imposing positive definiteness in the expression, we can obtain 3 bounds (114).

[image]

I do not understand how one equation can lead to 3 bounds from just positive definiteness. Also, while attempting to obtain $\tilde{k}_{ij,ij}$, the second and third terms of (112) become zero, which do not give any bound at all. Am I misunderstanding what has to be done?

Any answer which could explain these things would be very helpful.

Comment: The three conditions are something like tracing all four indices, contracting all four with $n$ and doing two of each right?

Comment: @ConnorBehan But taking the trace of the indices leads to zero as the second and third terms are inherently traceless